# Increase a numpy array's elements by 1 at particular indices (for use with grouping an astropy table)

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, astropy

That wasn't perhaps the best description in the title, but I can hopefully describe my problem below. There's really two parts to it.

The ultimate thing I'm trying to do is group certain times together within an astropy table - as the values are not the same for each time that will go into a particular group, I don't believe I can just give the column name in the [group_by()](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.table.Table.html#astropy.table.Table.group_by) method.

So, what I'm trying to do is produce an array describing which group each time with be associated with so that I can pass that to group_by(). I can get the bin edges by performing, for example (the 10 is arbitrary),

```
>>> np.where(np.diff(table['Times']) > 10)[0]
array([ 2,  8, 9, 12])
```

Let's say the table has length 15. What I want to know is how it might be possible to use that array above to create the following array without having to use loops

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4])
```

such that when I place that array in the group_by() method it groups the table according to those bin edges.

Alternatively, if there is a better way of grouping an astropy table according to time ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `np.digitize` should do what you want. Using `arr` in place of your table, try

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,15, 16, 17, 17, 18, 19, 30,41,42, 43, 55, 56])
bin_edges = arr[np.where(np.diff(arr) > 10)[0]]
indices = np.digitize(arr, bin_edges, right=True)
print indices
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach with [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) -

```
def repeat_based(bin_edges, n):
    reps = np.diff(np.hstack((-1,bin_edges,n-1)))
    return np.repeat(np.arange(bin_edges.size+1),reps)
```

Another approach with [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) -

```
def cumsum_based(bin_edges, n):
    id_arr = np.zeros(n,dtype=int)
    id_arr[bin_edges+1] = 1 
    return id_arr.cumsum()
```

Sample run -

```
In [400]: bin_edges = np.array([ 2,  8, 9, 12])

In [401]: repeat_based(bin_edges, n = 15)
Out[401]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4])

In [402]: cumsum_based(bin_edges, n = 15)
Out[402]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4])
```